# How to avoid append multiple times

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
$('.btn-default').click(function()
{
    var foldername = $('#file_title').val();
    $.post ('<?php echo  base_url(); ?>ClientCont/List_Files/inserttitle',{
        file_title:foldername
    },function(data){
        console.log(data);
    if(data['exist']== true ){
        if($('#notifme').length != 0){
            $('#notifme').append("Folder name already exist!");
            $('#notifme').show();
        }
    },'json');
});
```

Just wanted to ask, the code above is used to create a folder if the folder exists, I will notify the user that the folder is already in the database, but if the user click the button multiple times append execute multiple times. Please help how to avoid that #notifme is the name of my id for my alert thanks

Comment: Add a simple `if()` condition..... `if($('#notifme')){}` will return true if that element already exists. But you should actually append some element rather than appending text. You can use `.html()`  for that

Comment: Use, `html()` maybe instead of append.

Comment: @NewToJS `$(selector)` will always return true, regardless if matching elements exist or not. It always returns an object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use html() instead of append()

```
$('#notifme').html("Folder name already exist!");
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) method inserts specified content at the end of the selected elements i.e. It keeps on adding content on each event. [`html( htmlString )`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) sets the HTML contents of each element in the set of matched elements i.e it will replace the html of selected element with supplied html string. And [`text( text )`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) set the content of each element in the set of matched elements to the specified text i.e. it will replace the content of selected element. So you can use either [`html( htmlString )`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) or [`text( text )`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) to set the content in element.

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
    $('#notifme1').text("This is set by text()");
    $('#notifme2').html("<b>This is set by html()</b>")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="notifme1">
</div>
<div id="notifme2">
</div>

<button>Click me</button>
```